# WordPress multilevel menu on mobile device behavior

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I have a question, and for some logistical reasons I can't test it, and see for myself, so I am asking you :)

I have a multilevel navigation in wordpress, where top level pages have content that should be accessible when you click on it. Dropdown menu shows up on hover.

My question is: how will this behave on mobile devices where there is no hover state? Will on the first tap drop down be initiated or will the user be taken to the link behind the top level item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As on touch devices there can't be a hover state...so for that you can basically show the sub-links along with the main-link like a list.

- Link 1

  - Sub link 1
  - Sub link 2
  - Sub link 3
- Link 2

  - Sub link 1
  - Sub link 2
  - Sub link 3

Comment: i understand that, but when there is a hover state it is initiated with a tap, my question is what happens if there is a link on the same element, what will happen on the first tap: will the hover be triggered or the link?

Comment: it will first trigger the hover state displaying the sub-links and then trigger the page redirect.